# Hibernate Criteria join query

Tags: hibernate, criteria

How do I create a Hibernate criteria query from the following sql?

`String hql = "select e.employeeId,m.meetingId,e.firstname from Employee e join e.meetings m";`

Can anyone please provide the corresponding criteria query?

Comment: Have you tried to put the title of your question in a google search box?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

the criteria query is:

```
Criteria c = session.createCriteria(Employee.class, "e");
c.createAlias("e.meetings", "m"); // inner join by default
c.setProjection( Projections.distinct( Projections.projectionList()
            .add( Projections.property("e.employeeId"), "employeeId")
            .add( Projections.property("m.meetingId"), "meetingId")
            .add( Projections.property("e.firstname"), "firstname")));
```

Comment: Do we have to specify an all new .hbm.xml model for the return statement from this query?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
Criteria criteria = sessionFactory.getCurrentSession()
                                  .createCriteria(Employee.class)
                                  .createAlias("meetings", "m", JoinType.LEFT_OUTER_JOIN)
```