# Criteria Jpa Select foreign entity

Tags: sql, jpa, inner-join, hsqldb

Can anyone help to translate this hsql to criteria, please:

```
Select S From Player P Inner Join P.setting S Where P.id = :pid
```

I got confused working on this query.

Comment: possible dublicate look follow question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12512705/hibernate-criteria-join-query

Comment: The statement you have shown is not a valid SQL statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Even you are doing a JOIN, from your variable names it look to me like you modeled a `@OneToOne` relationship between `Player` and `Setting`, is it?

**If you modeled a `@OneToOne` relationship**, `Setting` will be EAGER loaded when a `Player` loads. Which means you could do a simple `em.find(Player.class, pid)` and use `player.getSetting()` to access it. If you still would like to this using the criteria API, go ahead with

```
public Player findByPlayerId(Long pid){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Player> cq = cb.createQuery(Player.class);
    Root<Player> playerRoot = cq.from(Player.class);
    cq.select(playerRoot);
    cq.where(cb.equal(playerRoot.<Long>get("id"),cb.parameter((Long.class), "playerId")));
    TypedQuery<Player> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    tq.setParameter("playerId", pid);
    return tq.getSingleResult();        
}
```

**If you modeled a `@OneToMany` relationship pointing from `Player` to `Setting`**, you may perform a JOIN because the mapping is LAZY loaded. In your case using the criteria API this can be done like this:

```
public List<Setting> getSettingsByPlayerId(Long pid){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Setting> cq = cb.createQuery(Setting.class);
    Root<Player> playerRoot = cq.from(Player.class);
    Join<Player, Setting> joinedSettings = playerRoot.join("setting"); //or better settings with an 's'
    cq.select(joinedSettings);
    cq.where(cb.equal(playerRoot.<Long>get("id"),cb.parameter((Long.class), "playerId")));      
    TypedQuery<Setting> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    tq.setParameter("playerId", pid);
    return tq.getResultList();
}
```

However, the translated SQL can be optimized to use fewer JOINS by optimizing the CriteriaQuery. Therefore you need to select the owning side of your mapping (which is `Setting`) instead of the non-owning side (`Player`).

```
public List<Setting> getSettingByPlayerId(Long pid){
    CriteriaBuilder cb = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
    CriteriaQuery<Setting> cq = cb.createQuery(Setting.class);
    Root<Setting> settingRoot = cq.from(Setting.class);
    cq.select(settingRoot);
    cq.where(cb.equal(settingRoot.<Player>get("player").<Long>get("id"),cb.parameter((Long.class), "playerId")));   
    TypedQuery<Setting> tq = em.createQuery(cq);
    tq.setParameter("playerId", pid);
    return tq.getResultList();
}
```